# How do I make a Caps Lock from a Seach Button?

Tags: ubuntu, search, capslock

So, I got a Lenovo Chromebook running the latest ubuntu Mate, and I really hate this Searcch button bringing up the top left corner menu. So, I decided that I will make a Caps Lock from it, but I am new at linux. I already searched the net, but nothing. Changed some the keycode thing, still nothing. As I found out, the key's keycode is 125. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @David58 and welcome to Unix & Linux! What exactly have you tried so far (commands you ran, configuration files you modified)? How do you know the keycode is 125? You can edit your question to add details at any time. Providing this information will make it more likely you get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where the "ubuntu Mate" come into the picture.

For the normal chromebook functionality you can click on the bottom right of the screen where the clock is, then click on the gearwheel to access the "settings". From there choose "device", and then "keyboard". There you are presented with options for what various keys do, including "search", "ctrl", "alt", "backspace" and "escape". One of the options is to use the "search" as "caps lock".

Edit: OP has clarified that this is now "like a normal laptop", so the normal techniques apply.

From memory, given the OP says the keycode generated by the Search key is 125 (perhaps found from the `xev` program)

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 125 = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'add lock = Caps_Lock'
```

should set the key to be `Caps_Lock` and then make the `Caps_Lock` key function as a caps lock.

There are other approaches, in particular loading a complete key map, which might be better.

Comment: I removed the whole Chrome system, so, it's now like a normal laptop. I decided to install Ubuntu Mate on it. But now, I am stuck with that search button.